# Shared variable in Laravel not available in layout

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I have 3 levels blade structure:

- lvl 0 - master-layout - containing elements common accross all system
- lvl 1 - module-layout - extending master-layout (via: `@extends('layouts.master-layout')`) with elements common for particular module
- lvl 2 - view-layout - layout for individual views extending module-layout (via: `@extends('layouts.module-layout')`)

In BaseController there are common methods sharing `$variable1` using `View::share('variable1', $variable1)`. I would expect `$variable1` to be available accross all views.

Yet when I call view-layout with viewController (extending BaseController) and try to use `$variable1` in **module-layout** it throws exception "**variable not defined**".

What is strange is that it works when I eliminate lvl 1 as intermediary and extend directly lvl 0 (using variable in view-layout). This means that `$variable1` is correctly shared but available is only at lowest level.

My question is how to make shared `$variable1` available in module-layout when calling view-layout which extends it? Should I somehow pass this shared variable separatly to extended layout?

Comment: I've just tested this on 4.2, but couldn't reproduce your error. I created a view that extends parents two levels up, shared a variable via View::share() and all three templates had it available. Perhaps there's something else going on?

Comment: Also tried this on 4.1 and there seems to be no error.